# What's the longest speedrun world record?

Tags: gaming-history, speedrun

Various classics have been speed run in surprisingly short amounts of time, for example Mario in [under 5 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-G8x-KiBLfw) and Ultimate Doom in [about 20 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNOnJ-gqQUY) and many others (Zelda, MineSweeper).

I learned that some people are speedrunning Final Fantasy VII, which doesn't seem like a game that would lend itself to speedrunning, due to its length.

Which game has the longest current world record in the 100% or any% speedrunning categories?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131110/discussion-on-question-by-stevec-whats-the-longest-speedrun-world-record).

Answer (score 38):

There are also a special type of speed run where lower % (less items) takes precedent over time.

Twilight princess has a glitch where it involves looking at a rupee for 17 hours to bypass significant portions of the game

https://www.speedrun.com/tpext/run/m7xl1r4y

The run is explained here:

Comment: As of July 2022, looks like the low % speedrun category has been removed

Answer (score 37):

As @Diehe posted, the longest one for a 100% run is definitely [this submission](https://www.speedrun.com/srotsm/run/z5o8095y) for **Spider: Rite of the Shrouded Moon** with 528h 16m 44s.
(It's worth noting that Snowfats is the only submitter of that category, so I'm not sure to define it a "record".)

Extra: [this submission](https://www.speedrun.com/baten_kaitos_eternal_wings_and_the_lost_ocean/run/y8r14kwm) for **Baten Kaitos: Eternal Wings and the Lost Ocean** with 338h 43m 26s.
(In this case the leaderboard has more than one runner, and it's an actual first place in its category.)

---

I also tried to find the longest one for Any%:

- [This submission](https://www.speedrun.com/digimon_world_2/run/mk8gvl3m)
  for **Digimon World 2** with 16h 59m 58s.
- [This submission](https://www.speedrun.com/xenogears/run/z13p2wgm) for **Xenogears** with 19h 41m 49s.
  (not an official category)

Feel free to point out if I missed something.

Comment: If we count the lone submission as an outlier, your second submission at 338h is also quite long. If that is a speedrun, I shudder to think how long a normal, take your sweet time completion would be.

Comment: @LoreFriendly for what I've understood, some items need to "evolve" and they take real time hours to do it. One of them requires 300 hours to reach its final form, so I think that's the only real problem for the speedrun, since several hours are spent to just wait...

Comment: @LoreFriendly If you just want to beat Baten Kaitos it can be easily done in under 50 hours. It's all the extra items that need to age to transform that make a "100% run" take all that time. They're absolutely optional and you really won't miss them.

Comment: I believe Shadow the Hedgehog 100% (no runs or even a registered category on speedrun.com, but I think someone's done it on youtube) takes multiple weeks to complete as well, since you have to complete the game some three hundred times to get every single title.

Comment: @Hearth Madness.

Comment: There are racing games that simulate the Le Mans. If you didn't know, Le Mans is a [24hr endurance race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24_Hours_of_Le_Mans). I wouldn't want to do a 100% "speed run" on any racing game that has any form of Le Mans...

Comment: @Nelson Project cars has a similar [trophy](https://psnprofiles.com/trophy/3543-project-cars/27-a-day-in-the-life) which requires a 24 real life hours race.

Comment: Wow, and here I thought Penn and Teller's desert bus would be a contender, since you *can't* Speedrun that part of their game, "The objective of the game is to drive a bus from Tucson, Arizona, to Las Vegas, Nevada, in real time at a maximum speed of 45 mph (72 km/h). The feat requires eight hours of continuous play in real time to complete." -wiki

Answer (score 16):

Slightly different type of game, but a strong mention for Runescape, specifically old school runescape as it takes longer to max.

A mod tweeted the record for fastest "Maxing" (highest level in each skill) to be ~2136 hours. This is just for one game mode where you can trade other players. For a gamemode "ironman" where you are on your own and cannot trade, the record is ~3400 hours.

This is also just for what we call maxing which is 99 in every skill. You can take this further by getting 200million xp in all skills which is the max amount of xp in a skill. A handful of players have done this now, which is estimated to take about ~15,000 hours.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/2007scape/comments/fwloo8/mod_lottie_via_twitter_least_time_until_2277/)

This equates to:

To put this into hours:
Normal: 2156
Ironman: 3522
Ultimate ironman: 4954
Hardcore ironman: 2863

Key points:

- Normal is the fastest because you can trade and buy supplies to level up with
- In Ironman game modes you play solo, you have to collect everything yourself and you cannot trade other players
- Ultimate ironman is the longest because you have no bank, you have 28 spots in your "bag" and have to use it wisely
- Hardcore ironman means you have 1 life, when you die you return to a normal ironman. Maxing this game mode tends to be faster than maxing a normal ironman because you tend to do less dangerous things such as bossing when you have one life, so you spend more time training and leveling up skills

Comment: Theomatrix says it can be done in 1700-1800h but the average player will need 2300-2500h. Is a quest cape included in your calculation? https://www.theoatrix.net/post/how-long-it-takes-to-max-in-osrs

Comment: @Jungkook, That theoatrix post is probably mathmatically correct, however i think it is pretty much impossible to do it in that time. The time stated by that site is if you play 1800 efficient hours. It is very unlikely that this will be done, 2300 is more likely as this allow for 500 inefficient hours e.g. collecting resources, doing some afk methods instead of the click intensive ones. That post also just uses the "fastest xp" methods which will not always be possible due to GP (gold pieces) restrictions, in which you will waste a lot of time (hundreds of hours) making the money to fund them

Comment: @Mageeg he probably also didn't include the time to do quests and diaries to get access to some of these high xp levels. The price is not really an option, I have friends that bought bonds with real money and sold them for GP in game to buy all the needed resources. This is of course not a viable method for people that don't want to spend a lot of $$$ on a speed run.

Comment: Very true, there are a lot of factors to think about. Really is crazy how much time people put into this game, there is no other game like it. People will easily play this game for ~18 hours a day

Comment: Something is wrong here, it is not possible for hardcore ironman to have a faster time than regular ironman, since regular ironman has options available to it that hardcore doesn't, but there are no options hardcore has that regular doesn't.

Comment: For what it's worth, a recall a player called A Friend maxing out on RS3 in about 72 game-time hours.

Comment: @corsiKa, Generally yes, it must just be the case that a normal ironman has not yet rushed max for a speedrun, I guess they just boss etc to get all the best items where as people rush HC max for ranks. If a normal Iron tried, it would be alot quicker due to what you said.

Comment: @J.Mini I remember this series, didn't he spend thousands and thousands of $$$ on treasure hunter? that's why i said specifically Old school runescape

Comment: @Mageeg I see these are ACTUAL speedrun times not estimated speedrun times.

Answer (score 8):

Honorable mention to [this 100% run](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLsjgeSw3vueF3WESbXv7BfvZ1Eh3cEkxn) of Animal Crossing with the added challenge that no Nook codes are used. There's no category for this specific restriction on speedrun.com, but the run itself comes in at 154:40:40 (over several sittings).

Answer (score 5):

Someone mentioned *Penn and Teller's Desert Bus*? Back in 2009, "Alden S." posted [an alleged *Desert Bus* speedrun of 1000 hours](http://tasvideos.org/2211S.html) — specifically, 1001:15:06, or a little under 42 days. Many online sites repeat this story as truth.

However, the specific *date* Alden S. posted his speedrun was 2009-04-01, so, I think it was intended to be taken with a pretty big grain of salt. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Someone is attempting a 100% run of Diablo 3 which includes all achievements, collectibles, and item collection of all unique Legendary, Ancient, and Primal items currently at 921hrs out of a estimated 6800hrs.
[Forum post with full rules from the runner](https://www.speedrun.com/d3_ros/thread/7frrh)

Answer (score 3):

The longest one I could find would have to be [This](https://www.speedrun.com/srotsm/run/ydqn97vm) run by Snowfats. It is an insane 528h 16m. There is also [this](https://www.speedrun.com/hwde/run/ywd8or9z) one, but it is currently second place in its category.

EDIT: I'm not sure what to make of [this](https://www.speedrun.com/hsce/run/m3n06k6y) one...

Comment: The rules of the last one ask for a longest time, so that one isn't a speedrun in any real sense (and I'm surprised speedrun.com allows a leaderboard to be configured that way)

Comment: @Unionhawk I was very surprised to see it too

Comment: Please describe what _this_ is. Answers should be useful without the need to click on links.

Answer (score 3):

Race games can be somewhat open-ended, though often have a career mode that includes a large number of races, some of them rather long.

Checking the Gran Turismo series on speedrun.com, GT4 has a 100% speedrun listed at 230h 35m 51 (https://www.speedrun.com/gt4/run/z053w5em). GT4 and GT5 have 24 hour races at Nurburgring and Le Mans, so if I'm reading it right (I never got that far) a strict 100% completion of GT4 would require 72 hours of endurance racing alone, twice at Le Mans and once at Nurburgring, and to complete the car collection you'd need to *win* at Nurburgring as well.

Answer (score 2):

Pokemon Stadium Complete the game category [took 19h 41m 57s](https://www.speedrun.com/pkmnstadium#Complete_the_Game)

Comment: Isn't this considered a 100% run?

Comment: @pinckerman Depends, there is no difference currently between 100% or any% for this game. It's not completionist based you see.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification